# Array Split in data frame column without warning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Data frame has columns 'date_sq'  and 'value', the 'value' column is an array of 201 columns.

```
| date_sq             | value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
| 2022-05-04 |13360\t12597\t13896\t8262\t12851\t12345\t12849\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t21320\t21301\t22597\t13624\t3\t0\t0\t0\t13360\t12597\t13896\t8262\t12851\t12345\t12849\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t21320\t21301\t22597\t13624\t2\t0\t0\t0\t13360\t12597\t13896\t8262\t12851\t12345\t12849\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t21320\t21301\t22597\t13624\t1\t0\t0\t0\t13360\t12597\t13896\t8262\t12851\t12345\t12849\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t21320\t21301\t22597\t13624\t0\t0\t0\t0\t13360\t12341\t13379\t8257\t14641\t13106\t12854\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t13123\t13139\t17473\t13105\t4\t0\t0\t0\t13360\t12341\t13379\t8257\t14641\t13106\t12854\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t13123\t13139\t17473\t13105\t3\t0\t0\t1\t13360\t12341\t13379\t8257\t14641\t13106\t12854\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t13123\t13139\t17473\t13105\t2\t0\t0\t1\t13360\t12341\t13379\t8257\t14641\t13106\t12854\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t13123\t13139\t17473\t13105\t1\t0\t0\t1\t13360\t12341\t13379\t8257\t14641\t13106\t12854\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t13123\t13139\t17473\t13105\t0\t0\t0\t1\t13360\t14644\t22099\t8257\t13105\t13879\t12853\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t16706\t21558\t17474\t13873\t4\t0\t0\t1\t2949\r\n |
```

My below codes works:

1. Split value column to 201 seperate column
2. Create date in numeric
3. Create a column 'key'
4. Drop unnecessary columns

```
df_spec[[f'{x}' for x in range(total_cols)]] = df_spec['value'].str.split (pat="\t", expand=True).replace(r'\s+|\\n', ' ', regex=True).fillna('0').apply(pd.to_numeric)

df_spec['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_spec['date_sq']).dt.strftime("%Y%m%d")

df_spec['key'] = (df_spec['date'].astype(str) + df_spec['200'].astype(str)).apply(pd.to_numeric)

df_spec.drop(['value','date_sq','date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Requirement:
My above code works, but it throws some warning messages.

1. Is there an optimized way without warnings?

Warning:

```
<ipython-input-3-70211686c759>:2: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  df_spec[[f'{x}' for x in range(total_cols)]] = df_spec['value'].str.split \
<ipython-input-3-70211686c759>:2: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  df_spec[[f'{x}' for x in range(total_cols)]] = df_spec['value'].str.split \

... goes on for some lines...
```

Final dataframe:

```
| 0     | 1     | 2     | 3    | 4     | 5     | 6     | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12    | 13    | 14    | 15    | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20    | 21    | 22    | 23   | 24    | 25    | 26    | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32    | 33    | 34    | 35    | 36 | 37 | 38 | 39 | 40    | 41    | 42    | 43   | 44    | 45    | 46    | 47 | 48 | 49 | 50 | 51 | 52    | 53    | 54    | 55    | 56 | 57 | 58 | 59 | 60    | 61    | 62    | 63   | 64    | 65    | 66    | 67 | 68 | 69 | 70 | 71 | 72    | 73    | 74    | 75    | 76 | 77 | 78 | 79 | 80    | 81    | 82    | 83   | 84    | 85    | 86    | 87 | 88 | 89 | 90 | 91 | 92    | 93    | 94    | 95    | 96 | 97 | 98 | 99 | 100   | 101   | 102   | 103  | 104   | 105   | 106   | 107 | 108 | 109 | 110 | 111 | 112   | 113   | 114   | 115   | 116 | 117 | 118 | 119 | 120   | 121   | 122   | 123  | 124   | 125   | 126   | 127 | 128 | 129 | 130 | 131 | 132   | 133   | 134   | 135   | 136 | 137 | 138 | 139 | 140   | 141   | 142   | 143  | 144   | 145   | 146   | 147 | 148 | 149 | 150 | 151 | 152   | 153   | 154   | 155   | 156 | 157 | 158 | 159 | 160   | 161   | 162   | 163  | 164   | 165   | 166   | 167 | 168 | 169 | 170 | 171 | 172   | 173   | 174   | 175   | 176 | 177 | 178 | 179 | 180   | 181   | 182   | 183  | 184   | 185   | 186   | 187 | 188 | 189 | 190 | 191 | 192   | 193   | 194   | 195   | 196 | 197 | 198 | 199 | 200  | key         |
|-------|-------|-------|------|-------|-------|-------|---|---|---|----|----|-------|-------|-------|-------|----|----|----|----|-------|-------|-------|------|-------|-------|-------|----|----|----|----|----|-------|-------|-------|-------|----|----|----|----|-------|-------|-------|------|-------|-------|-------|----|----|----|----|----|-------|-------|-------|-------|----|----|----|----|-------|-------|-------|------|-------|-------|-------|----|----|----|----|----|-------|-------|-------|-------|----|----|----|----|-------|-------|-------|------|-------|-------|-------|----|----|----|----|----|-------|-------|-------|-------|----|----|----|----|-------|-------|-------|------|-------|-------|-------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-------|-------|-------|------|-------|-------|-------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-------|-------|-------|------|-------|-------|-------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-------|-------|-------|------|-------|-------|-------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-------|-------|-------|------|-------|-------|-------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|-----|-----|-----|-----|------|-------------|
| 13360 | 12597 | 13896 | 8262 | 12851 | 12345 | 12849 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0  | 0  | 21320 | 21301 | 22597 | 13624 | 3  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 13360 | 12597 | 13896 | 8262 | 12851 | 12345 | 12849 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 21320 | 21301 | 22597 | 13624 | 2  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 13360 | 12597 | 13896 | 8262 | 12851 | 12345 | 12849 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 21320 | 21301 | 22597 | 13624 | 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 13360 | 12597 | 13896 | 8262 | 12851 | 12345 | 12849 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 21320 | 21301 | 22597 | 13624 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 13360 | 12341 | 13379 | 8257 | 14641 | 13106 | 12854 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 13123 | 13139 | 17473 | 13105 | 4  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 13360 | 12341 | 13379 | 8257 | 14641 | 13106 | 12854 | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 13123 | 13139 | 17473 | 13105 | 3   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 13360 | 12341 | 13379 | 8257 | 14641 | 13106 | 12854 | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 13123 | 13139 | 17473 | 13105 | 2   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 13360 | 12341 | 13379 | 8257 | 14641 | 13106 | 12854 | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 13123 | 13139 | 17473 | 13105 | 1   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 13360 | 12341 | 13379 | 8257 | 14641 | 13106 | 12854 | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 13123 | 13139 | 17473 | 13105 | 0   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 13360 | 14644 | 22099 | 8257 | 13105 | 13879 | 12853 | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 16706 | 21558 | 17474 | 13873 | 4   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 2949 | 202205052949 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and got no warnings. I hope it helps in your case

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2022-05-04', '13360\t12597\t13896\t8262\t12851\t12345\t12849\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t21320\t21301\t22597\t13624\t3\t0\t0\t0\t13360\t12597\t13896\t8262\t12851\t12345\t12849\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t21320\t21301\t22597\t13624\t2\t0\t0\t0\t13360\t12597\t13896\t8262\t12851\t12345\t12849\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t21320\t21301\t22597\t13624\t1\t0\t0\t0\t13360\t12597\t13896\t8262\t12851\t12345\t12849\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t21320\t21301\t22597\t13624\t0\t0\t0\t0\t13360\t12341\t13379\t8257\t14641\t13106\t12854\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t13123\t13139\t17473\t13105\t4\t0\t0\t0\t13360\t12341\t13379\t8257\t14641\t13106\t12854\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t13123\t13139\t17473\t13105\t3\t0\t0\t1\t13360\t12341\t13379\t8257\t14641\t13106\t12854\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t13123\t13139\t17473\t13105\t2\t0\t0\t1\t13360\t12341\t13379\t8257\t14641\t13106\t12854\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t13123\t13139\t17473\t13105\t1\t0\t0\t1\t13360\t12341\t13379\t8257\t14641\t13106\t12854\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t13123\t13139\t17473\t13105\t0\t0\t0\t1\t13360\t14644\t22099\t8257\t13105\t13879\t12853\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t16706\t21558\t17474\t13873\t4\t0\t0\t1\t2949\r\n']], columns=['date_sq', 'value'])
date = df['date_sq']

df = df['value'].str.split('\t', expand=True).fillna('0').apply(pd.to_numeric)# .explode().T.reset_index(drop=True)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(date).dt.strftime("%Y%m%d")

df['key'] = (df['date'].astype(str) + df[200].astype(str)).apply(pd.to_numeric)
df.drop(['date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df
```

I think `df_spec[[f'{x}' for x in range(total_cols)]]` is unnecessary when using `split(..., expand=True)`. Good luck

Comment: It works, but new warning message'     raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds'